# If the image of a linear transformation of normed spaces is finite dimensional, is the map bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V, W$ be normed spaces.  If $T: V \rightarrow W$ is such that $T(V)$ is finite dimensional, does it follow that $T$ is bounded?

Edit: This isn't a homework question, I'm just asking because I'm curious.  Good lord.

Edit: I have edited the question and title.  I originally called a $T$ such as one in the hypothesis "finite rank," whereas in the literature a transformation of finite rank is by *definition* a bounded linear transformation whose image is finite dimensional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be discontinuous linear functionals on an infinite-dimensional normed space. Such functions have one-dimensional ranges. You can use a few of these functions $\{ f_k \}_{k=1}^{n}$ with vectors $\{ x_k \}_{k=1}^{n}$ to define all kinds of discontinuous linear maps with finite-dimensional ranges:
$$
                Tx = f_1(x)x_1+f_2(x)x_2+\cdots+f_n(x)x_n.
$$
Finding a discontinuous linear function requires the axiom of choice. An easy method involves using the Axiom of Choice to find a Hamel basis $\{ e_{\alpha} \}$ for $X$, letting $\{ c_{\alpha} \}$ be an unbounded set of scalars, and defining a functional $f$ on this basis by
$$
                 f(e_{\alpha})=\frac{c_{\alpha}}{\|x_{\alpha}\|}.
$$
It's easy to check that $f$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You can think of this as a generalization of the fact that linear operators on finite vector spaces are bounded.

edit: nevermind, this was a misconception

Comment: Are you sure...? Consider a space $V = \bigoplus_n \mathbb{R} e_n$ with a countable basis $(e_n)$ of elements of norm $1$, and $W = \mathbb{R}$. Map $e_n$ to $n$ and extend linearly. This doesn't really look bounded to me. Even if what you say is true, you should include a proof, not rely on dogma...

Comment: Even worse, assuming choice there is an unbounded functional on every infinite dimensional normed space.

Comment: I don't know why someone edited out my recantation so I'll put it here.  My answer is incorrect (I guess it depends on what definition you take as finite rank but I think it was clear) and was a misconception of mine.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why I'm being downvoted, but as indicated by Najib Idrissi and Vincent Boelens, the claim is false.  If $V$ is any infinite dimensional normed space, let $v_1, v_2, ...$ be a countably infinite collection of linearly independent elements (normalized to have norm $1$).  Extend $\{v_i\}$ to a normalized basis $\{v_i\} \cup \{ w_j : j \in X\}$, and define $F: V \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $F(v_n) = n$ and $F(w_j) = 1$.

The quotients $\frac{|F(v_n)|}{||v_n||} = n$ are unbounded, so it follows that $F$ is not bounded.  We used the axiom of choice, since this is equivalent to the fact that every vector space has a basis.

Comment: There's really no need to invoke choice, since in this scenario you don't really need a _basis_, you just need infinitely many pairwise orthogonal non-zero vectors. I wouldn't think the $w_i$ are necessary to guarantee the existence of $F$.

Comment: In a Hilbert space we have a notion of orthogonality, but in a normed space we usually don't.  Even if we are in a Hilbert space, how do you define $F$ on all of $V$ without the existence of a basis?

Comment: @Arthur I don't know if you *need* choice (in the sense that the statement is equivalent to the axiom of choice), but as is it the argument heavily uses choice: how would you even construct a countable linearly independent set without the axiom of choice? (Or at least some kind of dependent choice) And I'm not an expert, but it wouldn't really surprise me if without choice, there were linear maps on a subspace that couldn't be extended to the whole space.